# How to subtract X days from a given string field storing Date in java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a string field which is returning a date value. I am trying to convert it into Date format and then subtract 30 days from it.

```
String extractDate; //2020-11-13 is the value
Date dateFormat= (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(onlyDate); //cannot parse Date error
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(dateFormat, -30);
```

How to perform this operation in a more better way?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `GregorianCalendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: The good answer by Vlad L solves your problems. Apart from using the outdated classes and a couple of minor points two things went wrong in your code: (1) Using `GregorianCalendar` for subtracting days involves more steps than what you tried; your code does not compile. (2) Your date string and your format pattern string don’t match: one has hyphens between the numbers, the other’s got slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date is being phased out, there are new classes you could use if you are OK with that (ie it is not compulsory to use Date). For example:

```
        String extractDate = "2020-11-13";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(extractDate);
        LocalDate newDate = date.minusDays(30);
        System.out.println(newDate);
```